# Getting several list of possibilities based on two list

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I struggle to solve a simple problem :

We have one list that represents demands and another entry_available. I need to take all the possible scenarios, where each demand can be grouped or not in the output and need to consider each value of entry_available as an independent center where we can fill one demand (or many demands) if possible.

Let me give you an example

```
demands = [4,3,8]
entry_available = [7,9,1]
```

Here the value 4 from demands can enter once in the first index of entry_available, the second but not the third. For the value 3 it can enter in 7 and 9 but not one, for 8 it can enter only in 9.
Now we also need to regroup demands based on entry_available where we deduct them meaning that values 4 and 3 can enter in 7 and value 8 will be forced to stay position 1 from entry_available which is 9.

We need to respect the size of entry_available where each value is a center from which we look to find possible combinations to fill an order  meaning if I have **entry_available = [5,19]** only (for example) the value 4 can enter in 5 once and values 3,8 has to be in 19 (because 19 - 3 - 8  >= 0) meaning we get this kind of output :

```
[4,[3,8]]
```

But remember that value 4 can in this example enter in 19 because 19 - 3 - 8 - 4 = 4 (>= 0) so we can fill all demands leaving one empty index of entry_available that we define by None

```
[None,[3,8,4]]
```

If we continue we see that 5 - 3 = 2 it can be filled in index 0 of entry_available and 19 - 4 - 8 = 7, 4 and 8 can be filled in the index 1 so we have

```
[3,[8,4]]
```

To summerise the function for this example gives us

```
[4,[3,8]],
[None,[3,8,4]],
[3,[8,4]]
```

Which as you can see uses all demands required for each combination.

Also to be clear if the size of demands is equal to the size of entry_available, we can also fill each demand without regrouping into a list of pairs or more only if entry_available[i] - demands[z] >= 0 and we can do as many regroups as possible only if all demands are used for it. If a center is not used we define it by None.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most appropriate way to solve your problem is [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).

Suppose your `demands` input does not contain 0.

```py
def find_comb(demands:list, entry:list):
    
    # Exit for dynamic programming
    if len(entry) == 1:
        if not demands: return [[[None]]]
        elif sum(demands) < entry[-1]: return [[demands]]
        else: return [-1]  # Not fulfill
    
    # Get all possible combinations for the entry[0]
    combs = [[0]]
    for d in demands:
        combs += [c + [d] for c in combs if sum(c) + d <= entry[0]]

    # Update [0] to [None] according to your request
    combs = [[x for x in c if x] if c != [0] else [None] for c in combs]

    # Get combinations
    ans = []
    for c in combs:
        res_demands = [d for d in demands if d not in c]
        for n in find_comb(res_demands, entry[1:]):  # Dynamic programming here
            if n == -1: continue
            if not n: n = [[None]] 
            ans.append([c] + [k for k in n])

    return ans
```

Testing

```py
print(find_comb(demands=[4, 3, 8], entry=[7, 9, 1]))
# [[4, 3], [8], [None]]

print(find_comb(demands=[4, 3, 8], entry=[5, 19]))
# [[None], [4, 3, 8]]
# [[4], [3, 8]]
# [[3], [4, 8]]
```

I suggest you keep all the elements in the same type (list), which reduces your complexity in dealing with the returns.

If you indeed need to turn the data into the same format as your example output, just do one more step.

```py
def clean_ans(rows):
    return [[x if len(x) > 1 else x[0] for x in row] for row in rows]

print(clean_ans(find_comb(demands=[4, 3, 8], entry=[5, 19])))
# [None, [4, 3, 8]]
# [4, [3, 8]]
# [3, [4, 8]]
```

Feel free to ask me in the comment if you stuck somewhere.

Comment: @w-ding i tried to make one more time this problem based on recursion like you did, so far i i found out it can be solved if we do it with one element here the var demands but permutated and we call a function like here (https://pastebin.com/cHYDRLw2) but i struggle to make it work

Comment: @silver743828 Hi silver, sorry I don't have time to fully go through your code today. The first thought I got is your code does not manage to exclude the "already used" elements for the next round recursion. My suggestion is to try to reduce the parameter inputs in the recursion function to reduce the complexity in coding. Currently, you have five inputs, which gives you extra burdens on maintaining the extra parameters. Considering the whole problem whth only two parameters will be cleaner and might be helpful.